# How to open a video popup on front page in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

We have a drupal 7 website. On frontpage of website we want a video popup to play a mp4 file as intro. Video will be hosted on our server. All suggestions are welcome. Thanks a lot! We love Drupal.

Comment: Please test this out with users. I'll leave the site right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Colorbox](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox) is a better alternative. You can just simply add a class to your link and it conveniently calls your link in a modal popup.

```
Ex. <a href="wwww.site.com" class="colorbox"> My Site. </ a>
```

Comment: Hi..Thanks for the reply. I want to open a mp4 video file in popup when a user visits front page.

Comment: I was able to open youtube video in colorbox on page load and play it automatically. But after it is finished how to close the colorbox automatically? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The [popup module](http://drupal.org/project/popup) allows to popup nodes, views and php-generated content. So first create a node with video , then use this popup to display it

Comment: Ok let me try and I will get back to you. Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: Hi Serjas. Can you please help with the code to programatically fire video popup in page--front.tpl.php using node id.

Comment: I could not find much in documentation of popup module